# Login with Facebook Popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, oauth, facebook-graph-api

User clicks on "Login with facebook" button, a popup is window dialog box is displayed.

How do I create this popup? (example www.break.com)

I can use this
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=email,user_birthday&client_id=123050457758183&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response&response_type=token

but there is no popup of cause, it just redirects the user directly to facebook.com, then returns to my site. It be nice to have a popup instead :-)

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

All of these social plugins require the user to login to their facebook site. You can choose a popup option when you build the embed code?

Is that what you are looking for? Or are you wanting to use Facebook as user authentication for your site?

Comment: No, looking at how to show only content for use within a popup see www.break.com and click on login with Facebook!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Facebook API: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/